# JMS closing client resources (MessageConsumer, Session, Connection)

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a simple JMS client and I would like to close all the JMS related resources at the end, i.e. instances of MessageConsumer, Session, Connection. Each of these classes has a close() method that throws a JMSException. I read I have to close all of them and closing an instance of a Connection is not enough. So this is what I have so far:

```
        try {
            consumer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

but if for example a consumer.close() throws an exception the session and the connection won't be closed. So a more correct approach would be:

```
    try {
        consumer.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    try {
        session.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

but it does not seem nice because of the code duplication. I find it hard to abstract it out more because none of these classes implement a common interface with a close() method (like Closable for example).

Do you know any better approach to close correctly all these 3 resources?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you close the parent the child is also closed so you can just close the session to close it's producers and consumer, or you can close the connection to close everything it created.

Comment: Do you have any links to support this? I'm hoping to do the same . Close session to close the producers/consumers.. But cant find any literature to support it.

Comment: Read the JMS specification, it's all defined in there.

Comment: Just for the sake of the next person wondering ... https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#close--
"There is no need to close the producers and consumers of a closed session."

Comment: Hmm, that seems a little ambiguous to me. Saying that "there is no need to close the producers and consumers of a closed session" is kind of obvious, since you can't close the producers and consumers if the session is already closed. Had the sentence said "there is no need to close the producers and consumers of a session you are about to close", I would have been more confident. But I guess that's a little pedantic.

Comment: I'll inform the grammar police of the issue